# move didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method to viewcontroller method with button trigger

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I had the following code working in AppDelegate.h/.m but cannot change it to work in ViewController with a button triggering it.

```
@implementation BSViewController

@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize workingImage;
- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender {

    UIImage* testCard = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad 7D.JPG"];
    CGImageRef num = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([testCard CGImage],CGRectMake(532, 0, 104, 104));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( 250,650));
    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextDrawImage(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 13, 13) ,num);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(num);

    UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:im];
    [self.imageView addSubview: iv];
    iv.center = self.imageView.center;
    [iv release];
```

I see the button named "Choose image" in the simulator, but I do not see the image there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added `self.imageView` to any views.
You need

```
[self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
```

To show your imageView.

Comment: I added that at various places with no apparent difference in results. Do I need to make more changes, too, or redo the action/outlet, or something else? – zerowords 12 secs ago edit

Comment: Finally I also added `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *workingImage;` and your answer worked. I wish I knew this earlier.

Comment: Great! Yes my apologies that you had to make the view you add a ``property`` if you are going to access it with ``self.`` .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work, but let me ask you some dummy questions before. You can skip these and jump directly to the end for the answer:

- Did it worked before?
- Why aren't you using ARC?
- Have you linked the `chooseImage:` to the button with Interface Builder, or programmatically? I sometimes forget this basic step, and nothing works of course :)
- Why are you adding `iv` as a subview of `self.imageView` instead of just changing the image property of `self.imageView`. Knowing this could be useful to answer properly.
- Supposing you have a good reason for adding `iv` as a subview, beware `iv.center = self.imageView.center` the centers are in two different coordinates system.
  Form the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview
>   and is measured in points. Setting this property changes the values of
>   the frame properties accordingly.
>   
>   **Edit: Other things to check**

- Does `self.imageView` exist? I mean, have you added it with IB and linked it to the IBOutlet, or defined it programmatically?
- Add a break point in `chooseImage:` and go through it step by step, making sure that the objects you generate there are not `nil`
- Test: try `self.imageView setImage:im` instead of `self.imageView addSubview:iv`, even if it's not what you want to do, if everything else is ok you should see the image.

---

It works if you switch the order of
`UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`
and
`CGContextDrawImage(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 13, 13) ,num);`

Otherwise you would be asking to create `im` with the content of the context without nothing in drawn in it.

The code would then become:

```
UIImage* testCard = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad 7D.JPG"];
CGImageRef num = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([testCard CGImage],CGRectMake(532, 0, 104, 104));
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( 250,650));
CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 13, 13) ,num);
UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGImageRelease(num);
```

Hope it helps. :D

Comment: I don't see any change with your code, either. By that I mean, no image ever shows on the simulator. IB "Sent Events" shows "Touch up Inside" connected to "File's owner chooseImage". Should I see an image after clicking the button even if I leave out the "iv" portion (so far I see nothing when eliding `iv`)? I am trying to eventually do image recognition on a small square within this image with a trained artificial neural net.

Comment: I am going to need some time to regroup and relearn this "hooking up" business.