# MainWindow.xib for ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, xib

I am trying to [build on this demo](http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/) which contains both a MainWindow.xib and a ImageManipViewController.xib . But my app contains the following code in the AppDelegate.m and my app does not (yet?) contain a MainWindow.xib. Is it better/best for me to add 2 MainWindow.xib files (one for iPhone and one for iPad) too (that are called in my method, each calling its own xib file) or is are the MainWindow.xibs just extra?

(Btw, if it turns out that the answer is that the MainWindow.xibs are redundant, then can you say why it might have been used in the original demo? Was it likely just a result of the author simplifying the steps in creating the demo, for example?) I have not found a way to contact the author directly.

If there is a better approach to developing a "universal" app, please advise me.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your main window and its attached subviews (and even view controllers) either programmatically or by using a Xib file. The result is the same, but small demo projects often use Xib files in order to simplify the code and focus on the part that they want to show you.

Two Xibs, one for iPad and one for iPhone is perfectly fine because iPad apps are encouraged to use views that make the most of the iPad large screen; for this reason, keeping them as separate files is recommendable. Your model and controllers should be common to iPad and iPhone, though.

And about loading Xibs, if your project is targeting iOS 4.0 or newer, you can name your xib files "BSViewController~iphone.xib" and "BSViewController~ipad.xib" and avoid some conditionals in your code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way to avoid conditionals. And so are you saying that the two "main" windows are the two viewControllers and no (intermediary) "main" windows are required or even desirable? I ask because in the demo, the MainWindow seems to really be used and is hooked up to the viewController xib.

Comment: Maybe I am asking if there needs to be a window, or can a viewController just exist autonomously (i.e. by itself) or does that line `self.window ...` imply there really is a Window.xib, too ?

Comment: @zerowords Every app must have a main window. It will be instantiated from the Xib file using the correct device screen size. The relationship between self.window and MainWindow.xib is represented by the outlet in ImageManipAppDelegate.h

Comment: I am taking your answer and comment to mean that no physical xib for mainWindow is required or even desirable in my case because the two viewController xibs together with the outlet designation in the AppDelegate.h files is all that I need. [I am trying to find why my app is not working and am fishing for problems.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305112/)

Comment: I am lost. I tried  (re-)naming my xib files "BSViewController~iphone.xib" and "BSViewController~ipad.xib" but Xcode terminated and when I relaunched, the ipad.xib was greyed out and I have not been able to recover. Everything I do either will not compile or gives errors I cannot understand. In the AppDelegate.h I have `@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;` and `@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet BSViewController *viewController;` In the navigator my file is named `BSViewController~iPad.xib` But no dragging in the xib will hook up anything to the File's Owner. Help, pls

Comment: Xcode itself aborts when I change the names to `~iPad.xib` and `~iPhone.xib` so this recommendation does not work for me. Please adjust the answer.

Comment: @zerowords Try ~iphone.xib and ~ipad.xib instead of ~iPad.xib and ~iPhone.xib. Then clean your project and reopen Xcode.