# creating a view controller for universal iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, ios-universal-app

**update 0**

Hold off on answering this question.

I think I have found part of the problem.

XCode aborted again when I tried to rename the automatically generated .xib files it had created with `_` to use `~`. Xcode seems to destroy at least one of the .xib files when it aborts, and that file contains the minimal view or window object needed by the app. Although the missing .xib file is gone from the Finder, it still shows in the Navigator.

So now, I am going to leave the `_` files alone and try again, but not use the suggestion I got earlier.

**update 0**

I am having trouble with my xibs having changed the following code [as recommended here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341605/)
I suspect the problem comes from changing the xib names to using '~' instead of '_' and not being able to revise the corresponding code which refers to the xib names.

The problem could also be that I have the following 4 filenames which could be confusing to Xcode?

BSViewController.h/.m

BSViewController~iPhone.xib

BSViewController~iPad.xib

Original code **was**.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Altered code (including extra) **is**.

```
#import "BSAppDelegate.h"

#import "BSViewController.h"
@implementation BSAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

BSAppDelegate.h follows.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BSApp;
@class BSViewController;
@interface BSAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    UIWindow *window;
    BSViewController *viewController;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet BSViewController *viewController;
@end
```

BSViewController.h follows.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BSViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIImage *workingImage;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *workingImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

+ (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable;
- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender;
- (IBAction) grayscale:(id) sender;

@end
```

BSViewController.m follows.

```
#import "BSViewController.h"

@interface BSViewController ()

@end

@implementation BSViewController

@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize workingImage;

+(BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable
{
    BOOL isCameraAvailable=NO;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] )
            isCameraAvailable = YES;
    }
    return isCameraAvailable;
}

- (IBAction) chooseImage:(id) sender {
    [self.view addSubview: self.imageView];
    UIImage* testCard = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad 7D.JPG"];
    CGImageRef num = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([testCard CGImage],CGRectMake(532, 0, 104, 104));
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( 250,650));
    CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawImage(con, CGRectMake(0, 0, 13, 13) ,num);
    UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(num);
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.workingImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:self.workingImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [workingImage release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I am using Xcode 4.5.2 and designing for iOS 6.

In my `BSViewController~iPad.xib` I have added a "ViewController" object which upon control-clicking produces 2 Outlets: "searchDisplayController" and "view". There is no "view" top-level object; when I try to drag the "+" to the "File's Owner" I get no result and probably shouldn't.

In my `BSViewController~iPhone.xib` I have already a "Window" object, and don't know if that is good or needs to be also added to the the ~iPad.xib (but I don't know how).